# Sorting (Vector of Objects)

Tags: c++, vector

I'm a new programmer in C++ and I'm stuck with a problem:

I have this class:

```
class car{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    car();

    //Overload Constructor
    car(string, int, float, float);

    //Desctructor
    ~car();

    //Access Functions
    string getbrand() const;
    int getyear() const;
    float getkm() const;
    float getprice() const;

    //Mutator Functions
    void setbrand(string);
    void setyear(int);
    void setkm(float);
    void setprice(float);

private:
    //variables
    string newbrand;
    int newyear;
    float newkm;
    float newprice;


};
```

//Access Functions

```
string car::getbrand() const{
    return newbrand;
}

int car::getyear() const{
    return newyear;
}

float car::getkm() const{
    return newkm;
}

float car::getprice() const{
    return newprice;
}
```

So, once I've started to insert my cars I've put them in a vector:

```
void fillvector(vector<car>& newmyfleet){

    string brand;
    int year;
    float km;
    float price;

    cout << "How many cars do you want in your fleet? ";
    int fleetsize;
    cin >> fleetsize;

    for (int i = 0; i < fleetsize; i++){

        cout << "Car Brand: ";
        cin >> brand;

        cout << "Car Year: ";
        cin >> year;

        cout << "Car Kms: ";
        cin >> km;

        cout << "Car Price: ";
        cin >> price;

        car newcar(brand, year, km, price);
        newmyfleet.push_back(newcar);
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

---

So my question is this: How can I sort all my cars, from the vector, by brand?!!
I've tried using sort but I cannot...

This was my last solution:

//function 1

```
bool sortbybrand(car &c1, car &c2) { return c1.getbrand() < c2.getbrand(); }
```

//sorting

```
void sbrand(const vector<car>& newmyfleet){

    unsigned int size = newmyfleet.size(); //Number of cars

    sort(newmyfleet.begin(), newmyfleet.end(), sortbybrand);

    cout << "Sorting Cars by Brand\n\n " << endl;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            cout << "Car: " << i + 1 << endl;
            cout << "Car Brand: " << newmyfleet[i].getbrand() << endl;
            cout << "Car Year: " << newmyfleet[i].getyear() << endl;
            cout << "Car Kms: " << newmyfleet[i].getkm() << endl;
            cout << "Car Price: " << newmyfleet[i].getprice() << endl;
            cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: A `const vector<car>& newmyfleet` isn't going to be nice about providing a set of iterators that can be used to **modify** the vector. Lose the `const`. While you're at it, add `const` to *both* parameters of your comparator, and have your `getbrand()` function return a `const std::string&` unless you plan on its results every participating in a move-assignment.

Comment: google `std::qsort()` or `std::sort()` examples, there are plenty and thorough. In any case, you should also provide a compare function for custom results